# Why does my Block[]ed variable not apply?

Tags: numerical-integration, scoping, crash

Consider the following example:

```
(* This in the first cell *)
ACf[z_] = Sqrt[2 + M - (M z^2)/2];
ABf[z_] = Sqrt[4 + 2 M - M z^2]/Sqrt[2 + M];
J[h_, z_] = h/Sqrt[2 M + 4 - 2 h^2 - M z^2];


(* This in the second cell *)
Block[{M = 10},
 NIntegrate[
  J[(Min[z, ACf[z]] - ABf[z]) t + ABf[z], z], {z, Sqrt[2 + M]/Sqrt[
   1 + M], (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 + M])/Sqrt[M]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"]
 ]
```

With fresh kernel I evaluate the contents of the first cell. Then after the evaluation is finished, I evaluate the second one. And the result is:

> NIntegrate::nlim: z = Sqrt[2.0000000000000000000+M]/Sqrt[1.0000000000000000000+M] is not a valid limit of integration.
>
> NIntegrate[
>    J[(Min[z, ACf[z]] - ABf[z]) t + ABf[z], z], {z, Sqrt[2 + M]/Sqrt[
>     1 + M], (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 + M])/Sqrt[M]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
>    WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"]

In some cases, instead the kernel just quits without having printed anything.

I reproduce this in Mathematica 11.0, but not in 9.0.

What's happening here? In Mathematica 9.0 I get just `NIntegrate::slwcon`, not such strange errors as in 11.0.

Comment: I think there is a bug with NIntegrate here

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the fact that when specifying `Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"`, this integral simply won't evaluate at all.  What it doesn't, I do not know.  But it explains the behaviour you see.

Let's drop the `Block` and evaluate

```
M = 10;

NIntegrate[J[(Min[z, ACf[z]] - ABf[z]) t + ABf[z], z],
 {z, Sqrt[2 + M]/Sqrt[1 + M], (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 + M])/Sqrt[M]}, {t, 0, 
  1},
    WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"]
(* NIntegrate[
 J[(Min[z, ACf[z]] - ABf[z]) t + ABf[z], z], {z, Sqrt[2 + M]/Sqrt[
  1 + M], (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 + M])/Sqrt[M]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"] *)
```

It's returned as is.

What happens if we `M =.`, then

```
Block[{M=10},
   NIntegrate[...]
]
```

?

Well, it will first evaluate with `M` having a value within a block.  The result is the same `NIntegrate`, with no change (i.e. no evaluation).  This is what is returned from the `Block`.  But when it's returned, `M` loses its value, so the expression evaluates again, a second time.  This time `M` has no value and you see the error you mentioned.

Removing this `Method` specification allows the evaluation to finish.

There is no mystery related to `Block`.  The real question is: why doesn't this integral evaluate at all?  I don't remember ever seeing `NIntegrate` return as entered ...  `Integrate` does that often when it can't compute the result.  But I have not seen it with `NIntegrate`.

Comment: But when `NIntegrate` returns unevaluated result, why is the evaluation then restarted?

Comment: @Ruslan I don't have a full understanding of how this works, but it seems clear enough that if it didn't work this way, that would mess things up.  Consider `f[x_?NumericQ] := x` and `x=1;`  Then try `Block[{x}, Echo@f[x]]`.  It would be quite weird if the evaluation were not restarted after `f[x]` is returned from `Block`.  What exactly triggers the restart?  I don't know.  Maybe just a simple value change (`x` changed).

Comment: @Ruslan See also `Update`.  It deal exactly with situations when the evaluation *should* be restarted but the system doesn't do this on its own.  I am not experienced with `Update`.

Comment: Another factor is `NIntegrate` is `HoldAll`, so that its arguments are returned with `M` unevaluated. -- I agree with your comment that leaving `Block` resets `M` and triggers a new evaluation cycle. This is explicitly mentioned at the end of the tutorial [Blocks and Local Values](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BlocksAndLocalValues.html).

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment: What I present below is just a side issue to what's going on with `Block`, which Szabolcs has already explained. The integrand is not a good candidate for the trapezoidal rule, since it has an infinite singularity at `t == 1` for `z > Sqrt[2]`. The integral is convergent, but the trapezoidal rule has trouble approximating its value.

The following is a simpler example of the numerical issue with `NIntegrate` and the `"TrapezoidalRule"`.  Having a function like `Min`, which is decomposed into piecewise components by `NIntegrate`, seems to be a key factor in reproducing the problem.

```
NIntegrate[Min[y, 1/2]/Sqrt[1 - x],
 {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"]
```

[image]

It also **crashes the kernel** sometimes. It seems always to crash if you try to [`Trace[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) it.

Note that like the OP's integrand, this has an infinite singularity, and while the integral is convergent, it returns unevaluated.  Also note the single integral

```
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[1 - x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"]
```

evaluates to a number, albeit with convergence warnings.